# how to update / delete uploaded image in mvc5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I save the images in this way directly to the database,
Please, I want to know how to edit and delete the same way
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdv7W.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It remains the same as you have added but difference is that the type of SQL query instead of Create it will be update or delete based on actions.

The file uploader works in same way to pick the file and access it using stream or bytes array.